# Autocomplete not finding route

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm trying to create an autocomplete with laravel and I'm using https://gist.github.com/imranismail/10200241
to get it to work.

The problem I'm having is that I keep getting a 404 and that the route isn't being found.

Here is my code

my blade file

```
<input type="text" id="q" name="q">

@push('js')
    <script>
        $(function()
        {
            $( "#q" ).autocomplete({
                source: "search/autocomplete",
                minLength: 3,
                select: function(event, ui) {
                    $('#q').val(ui.item.value);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
@endpush
```

This is my web route

```
Route::get('/search/autocomplete', [ProductController::class, 'autocomplete']);
```

and this is my autocomplete function

```
public function autocomplete()
{
    $term = request('name');

    $results = [];

    $queries = DB::table('products')
                        ->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$term.'%')
                        ->take(5)
                        ->get();

    foreach($queries as $query)
    {
        $results[] = [
            'id' => $query->id,
            'value' => $query->name
        ];
    }

    return Response::json($results);
}
```

Comment: try  `source: "search/autocomplete",` to `source: "/search/autocomplete",`

Comment: I'm still getting the 404

Comment: check full url and check you `php artisan route:list` to confirm  https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote

Comment: So I managed to fix it my using a named route, but now even though I'm getting the correct product names, it isn't showing up in my ui

Comment: @Aurilie Did you try `php artisan route:clear`?

Answer (score 0):

change to ajax call

```
          $.ajax({
            url: '{{ url('make_autocomplete') }}',
            method:"POST",
            data:{boat_type_id:boat_type_id, _token:_token},
            success:function(data){
              //console.log(data);
              // successtask
            }
          });
```